# .net core 2.0 cookie authentication getting stuck in infinite redirect loop when trying to access over https

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core-2.0, startup, cookie-authentication

I have just moved my code to our QA environment which uses https and what was working in Dev is not working in QA because the browser gets stuck in an infinite redirect loop.  Our load balancer forces https so when the login redirect happens from code, which for some reason it's trying to redirect to http instead of https, the load balancer is stopping it and adding https again which causes the infinite loop.  The question I have is why is this code not just redirecting to https, the path is relative in the `ConfigureServices()` method.  I've looked at it in fiddler, and it is indeed adding the FQDN for the redirect with http instead of https.

Is there some property I need to add to options here to allow https redirects?

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Account/LogIn";
                options.LogoutPath = "/Account/LogOff";
            });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseAuthentication();
    }
```

thanks.

Comment: UseHttpsRedirection looks to fit the scenario. Here is a link to the information, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder looks to only be available in .net core 2.1 and I'm on 2.0.5.  Also, this approach seems to be for forcing https which our load balancer is already doing.  Perhaps it would resolve my problem, but isn't there some way to just make the redirect happen over https if that's where the request is made?

Comment: If you turn off the load balancer does it do the same thing?

Comment: I can't turn off the load balancer.  I can hit each node individually using the server names directly (but that's on http) and it works fine with that.  The way our LBs work is they capture the traffic (either on port 80 or port 443) then pass the request on to the individual nodes on some high port according to the site being requested (ie 40077).  We have a ton of regular .net apps running with MVC, but this is my first go at a .net core app and have hit this challenge.  All of the regular .net mvc apps redirect correctly using the authentication process from web.config.

Comment: Check into how your headers appear by following this article: https://codeopinion.com/configuring-asp-net-core-behind-a-load-balancer/ "X-Forward-For" looks like a possible suspect. -this is more new to me as well

Comment: I've added the suggested code from that article `app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions...` and still seeing the same behavior.

Comment: I will check with the infrastructure guys to see if they can maybe add the proto header to indicate that it needs to be https, I think that could be the problem as fiddler isn't showing that header in the request.

Comment: @Programmer so our infrastructure guys are neck deep in an azure issue today and can't get to adding that header to the LB for requests to the app behind the LB.  I did however make a Postman request with the header added and it looks like it's going to work.  If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: As long as you solved your issue I am good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just use:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {           
        ... //settings and logging initialization
        app.Use((context, next) =>
        {
            context.Request.Scheme = "https";
            return next();
        });
        ... //all the rest middleware calls
    }
```

and it helps in most situations under OWIN and .Net Core up to 2.0

Comment: just for the heck of it, I tried this solution and it worked as well.  This is much cleaner and simpler than what I did before so I'll accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Programmer's suggestion in the comments to the OP, I took a look at this: https://codeopinion.com/configuring-asp-net-core-behind-a-load-balancer/  It describes my situation exactly (ssl termination at the load balancer and the .net core 2.0 app redirecting to http for login).  I then tried making the request through the LB with the header the article suggests and adding in the `Configure()` method of the `Startup` class this piece of code:

`app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
            });`

what was interesting is that when I made a request including the proto header:

`X-Forwarded-Proto:https`

from outside the LB, it passed that header through to the app and it worked great, no more infinite redirect loop.  However when our infrastructure guys added that header to the request that the LB makes to the internal nodes behind the LB, I was getting a redirect to https, yay, but it was also prepending the ip address to the redirect URL (we have a netscaler LB).  Apparently by default when you add a custom header, there's a checkbox to include the IP to the internal node and that had to be unchecked.  After that was done, we're in business.

thanks again @Programmer for your help. You definitely pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

For .net core 2.1 and up with azure authentication try this code.

```
 services.Configure(AzureADDefaults.CookieScheme, options =>
    {
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
             .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```